# How to rename Redis command in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5, redis, predis

I'm using Laravel 5.7 with Redis. In my Redis config I renamed some commands following the tutorial [Step 5 - Renaming Dangerous Commands](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04) in DigitalOcean. I added those lines as an example:

```
rename-command DEL CODE_DEL
rename-command CONFIG CODE_CONFIG
...
```

Now I get error in Laravel 5.7

```
ERR unknown command `DEL`, with args beginning with: ...
```

because actual command is now `CODE_DEL`.

Is there a way to tell Redis use `CODE_DEL` instead of `DEL` command?

Comment: Any update on this

Comment: Nope. I opened an Issue on Laravel for this. I would have to hack Laravel Redis driver code for that, but I stay away from that pratice. I'm using it normally and waiting.